# Trying to remove a class with JavaScript, element doesn't take properties of other class

Tags: javascript, html, css

So whenever the scrollTop of my page reaches 1, it will automatically scroll down to another location on the page (this is demonstrated in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YSbakker/1Lf7Louj/) more clearly). This does work, but however trying to remove a class from a menu item (so that it becomes "unselected"), problems occur. The element doesn't seem to get the properties of the other class and shows as standard text (again, look at the JSFiddle for a demonstration). I was wondering how to fix this.

The following code is where my problems occur:

```html
<div id="homeButton" class="menuItem selected">Home</div>
<div id="overButton" class="menuItem">Over</div>
<div id="contactButton" class="menuItem">Contact</div>
```

```css
.menuItem {
    padding-top: 29px;
    height: calc(100% - 29px);
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Signika;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(203, 207, 218);
}
.selected {
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(59, 89, 202);
    height: calc(100% - 33px);
    color: rgb(160, 170, 218);
}
```

```js
var homeButton = document.getElementById("homeButton");
var aboutButton = document.getElementById("overButton");

homeButton.className = homeButton.className - " selected";
aboutButton.className = aboutButton.className + " selected";
```

Comment: Is that minus sign intentional? Because it doesn't make any sense if it is (the plus sign is also a concatenation operator, which is what the second line does, it adds a string to the string value; there is no minus concatenation operator).

Comment: Also, see [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which is much easier than toggling classes manually.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for your input, but another answerer has given me an easier JQuery solution which I'm going to use. The minus sign is indeed intentional but I guess I misinterpreted the use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
$("#homeButton").removeClass( "selected" );
$("#overButton").addClass( "selected" );
```

instead of

```
var homeButton = document.getElementById("homeButton");
var aboutButton = document.getElementById("overButton");

homeButton.className = homeButton.className - " selected";
aboutButton.className = aboutButton.className + " selected";
```

Comment: Yeah, I see you edited your post correctly ;) Thanks, that just did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the menuItem class.

```
homeButton.className = homeButton.className - " selected";
homeButton.className = "menuItem";
aboutButton.className = aboutButton.className + " selected";
```

But I recommend that you remove and add classes with [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) instead.